# Mediation Analysis with Only Indirect effect

Tags: mediation

Currently doing a mediation analysis for the following research framework (A -> mediated by C-> E)

[image]

With such a framework, there's an indirect effect of mediation and no direct effect.
Can the mediation analysis still be done and are there any references to support this?

Answer (score 0):

You ask about "the" mediation analysis, but I'm not sure which mediation analysis you mean. Typically mediation analysis is used to answer the questions of whether there is an indirect effect(and how large it is) and whether there is a direct effect (and how large it is). If you feel like you know that the graph above describes your model and you do not want to test for the presence of a direct effect, you can just fit that model as a system of structural equations (i.e., a structural equations model). This can be done using, e.g., `lavaan` in R or `sem` in Stata. Structural equation modeling allows you to test whether the restrictions you have placed on the model (i.e., the absence of direct effects) fit the data well and allows you to estimate and test the coefficients that describe the relationship indicated by the arrows in your diagram.